# Google apps script, can not include css

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm newbie at google apps script. I have tried some examples, which work fine, but I've stuck with including css file.

In my code.gs I've created include function:

```
function include(filename) {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
}
```

As well I've created css file "Sidebar.css.html", which contains some style parameters:

```
<style>
.branding-below {
 bottom: 56px;
 top: 0;
}

.branding-text {
left: 7px;
position: relative;
top: 3px;
}

.col-contain {
overflow: hidden;
}

.col-one {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

.logo {
vertical-align: middle;
}

.radio-spacer {
height: 20px;
}

.width-100 {
width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

In my Sidebar.html I've tried to include the css:

```
<?!= include('Sidebar.css.html'); ?>
```

which apparently didn't work. Here is result:

In this link you can see the result(I dont have enough rep. to post it, sorry): http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0005/1191/378023/150727/371cdf01c0.jpg

What can I do about it?

Comment: Have you explicitly inputted ".html"? If not, don't include it, just the file's name, `<?!= include('Sidebar.css'); ?>`. If you have, share the whole code.gs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed showSidebar() to:

```
function showSidebar() {
var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar').evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle('Translate');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

Which works not only correct, but even faster due to using 'IFRAME'

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `createHtmlOutputFromFile`, you'll want to use `createTemplateFromFile` and `evaluate` the template. Your code for adding the sidebar should look like this:

```
function showSidebar() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar');
  var ui = template.evaluate().setTitle('Translate');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works now, but to be honest, I have no clue why - the variant with   using createHtmlOutputFromFile was taken from official google apps sript example.

Comment: `<?= ... ?>` is a scriptlet which needs to be executed. The method for loading templated HTML is different from serving basic HTML. More information about templates can be found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Answer (score 0):

> In my Sidebar.html I've tried to include the css: 
>   `<?!=include('Sidebar.css.html'); ?>`

I did this same thing but didn't include `.html`.  Also, I made sure that **the case of the filename in my code matched the case of the actual filename**.  In Google's example that you followed they have the CSS file capitalized in the code for some reason but it has to match the actual filename.

Answer (score -4):

Have you declared what the HtmlService variable is?

Comment: No, and I dont think I have to - HtmlService is a class and I invoke it's static method.

Comment: HtmlService is a GAS global object.